# array of strings with pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char **pps;

    int i, n = 10;

    char name[256];

    pps = (char **)calloc(n,sizeof(char **));

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n Enter name[%d]: ",i+1);
        gets(name);
        printf("\n Name=%s len=%d",name,strlen(name)+1 );

        pps[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(name)+1);
        printf("\n pps[i]=%u",pps[i]);
        if (pps[i] = NULL)
        {
            perror("\nerror in malloc");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("\n pps[i]=%u",pps[i]);
        strncpy(pps[i],name,strlen(name)+1);
    }

}
```

/* input/output from program:
     Enter name[1]: abcdef

```
 Name=abcdef len=7
 pps[i]=13311184
 pps[i]=0
```

*/

**The program gives Runtime Error ???
Please help to find what is wrong and why PPS[i] become currupted ???
I am using visual studio 2010**

Comment: And don't put a `printf` between your failing `malloc` and the related `perror`.  (`printf` may change `errno` and make the `perror` less than useless.)

Comment: Try to adjust warning level higher, because `if (pps[i] = NULL)` should give you a warning! Or if you already got a warning, then consider not ignoring the warnings, but actually fixing them... They're there for a reason!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if (pps[i] = NULL)
```

It should be:

```
if (pps[i] == NULL)
```

Remember that `=` is an assignment operator while `==` is comparation

Also remember to use `free` at the end of your program to avoid memory leak.